# Expression Engine Allowed File Types Option

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine

When creating an upload destination in EE2 is it possible to add more options to the "Allowed File Types" drop down http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/content/files/file_upload_preferences.html#allowed-file-types as it only gives you two options "ALL" or "Image". This seems a bit insecure if you want to create a frontend PDF upload to have to select the "ALL" option.

What would be ideal is if I could make a file group and select the appropriate MIME types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond hacking the core in many places, there is no solution to this. I'd suggest posting a [feature request](http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewforum/106/) - it's a good idea (even if it was just preconfigured with a few standard filetypes listed with checkboxes).

Comment: cheers for answering all my EE query's. I will keep hunting but if I find this to be true I will give you the tick. cheers

Comment: I will award you with this bounty because I cant find an alternative to this answer and you have been excellent in answering all my EE questions.

Comment: Very kind, glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no way (as far as I know) to to this without hacking the core files of Expression Engine the only way to do it would be to use the "ALL" option and add (and possibly remove) mimetypes from system/expressionengine/config/mimes.php to restrict/expand the accepted types.

Anyway, it's not recommended as a best practice to edit the core files as it can conflict with later updates. You should (as Theo Kouzelis recommends) file a feature request.